# Telegram client to listen for channel updates

Tags: telegram

I need a way to automate processing of messages/files sent in a Telegram channel. I've been told that is can't be done with a telegram bot since they can't join channels, nor am I the owner of the channel, so I would need to set up a client or to use regular Telegram API to be able to do that. I'm looking for guidance, suggestions, anything that could help me. The script/client will have to run on Windows (so I can't use the cli linux version).

Answer (score 2):

You can try **UNOFFICIAL** [PWRTelegram](https://pwrtelegram.xyz/) API, it can be login in use a user account, and have HTTP API like bots.

You can click [here](https://daniil.it/MadelineProto/API_docs/methods/) to see usages.